# how show a preview of binary.fields in odoo 11

Tags: odoo-11

**I am beginner**, my questions is... how show a binary.fields preview in new tab or pop-up?, my version is odoo-11, the files is any upload (docs, image, etc..) i see in module mail something but i not understand code.

i see more question for this, but in v11 don't work for me.

my code is simple:

```
.py:
fpath = fields.Binary(string='upload', attachment=True)

view.xml
<field name="fpath" filename="name" widget='binary'/>
```

thanks for you answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<field name="fpath" widget="image"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solved the problem with images, but not with the docs, in this moment, i used a module named Muk Documents, that solve my problem, tanks for your time.